# Is it possible to get e-mail source using JavaMail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I use JavaMail API to download mails via IMAP. I want to save them locally, in files. I have a DB, but I only want to store some meta-data in it (like mail file location).

Is there a possibility, using the JavaMail API, to get the actual source of an e-mail? Like in Outlook via context menu on a mail in a list and 'View Source'.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: You find a comprehensive introduction how to use the API here Fundamentals of the JavaMail API which provides many examples as code snippets
Maybe you can find some stuff here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more API reading I've found a solution.

```
javax.mail.Part#writeTo(OutputStream)
```

does the thing.